# Use Firebase Analytics for User Analytics

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

Is it possible to use Firebase Analytics for In App Analytics.

I want to track when a person open another user's profile like this:

```js
import { getAnalytics, logEvent } from "firebase/analytics";

const analytics = getAnalytics();
logEvent(analytics, 'open_profile', {
  profileId: '1234'
});
```

So now I want to show the user with id `1234` how many times the `open_profile` event occurs where the `profileId` is `1234`.

Is this possible with Firebase?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can track all the events in the application by creating **custome events** and we can also view each individual events and its count in firebase dashboard.

[image]

Comment: so It is also possible to get the results back from firebase in like a React Native app?